# Telerik gridview export images not working winforms

Tags: c#, image, winforms, export, telerik-grid

I am trying to export the following gridview (winforms project) with Telerik export library:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
            ExportToPDF pdfExporter = new ExportToPDF(this.SystemGridView);
            pdfExporter.FileExtension = "pdf";
            pdfExporter.ExportVisualSettings = true;
            pdfExporter.HiddenColumnOption = HiddenOption.DoNotExport;
            pdfExporter.PdfExportSettings.EnableCopy = true;
            pdfExporter.RunExport(filename);
```

It's possible to export images with this library?
I've found a [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-image-export-to-pdf), but it's outdated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found:

```
GridViewPdfExport pdfExporter = new GridViewPdfExport(this.radGridView1);
pdfExporter.RunExport(@"C:\New.pdf", new PdfExportRenderer());
```

[Link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-exporting-data-export-to-pdf.html#GridViewPdfExport)