# telerik gridview export to pdf in win forms

Tags: telerik, export-to-pdf, radgridview

telerik gridview export to pdf in win forms.

hi i want to get pdfexport from telerik grid and i search on the web and find answer on [Telerik gridview export images not working winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097915/telerik-gridview-export-images-not-working-winforms/72080978#72080978)

```
private void RunExportToPDF(string fileName, ref bool openExportFile)
    {
        GridViewPdfExport pdfExporter = new GridViewPdfExport(this.dataGridView1);
        pdfExporter.RunExport(@"C:\New.pdf", new PdfExportRenderer());
  
    }
```

but i still have error. any one can help me??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXFMp.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In your screenshot, what does the popup error description say when you hover over the red underline?  Have you included the necessary library at the top of RadForm2.cs to make `PdfExportRenderer()` accessible?

Comment: hi Ben Bloodworth
yes i using necessary namespace , using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Telerik.Data;
using Telerik.WinControls.UI;
using Telerik.WinControls;
using Telerik.WinControls.UI.Export;
using TelerikWinFormsApp1.Models;